# Как узнать, скачивал ли пользователь приложение ранее?

Tags: ios, php, appstore

Как определить, скачивал ли пользователь приложение из App Store ранее?

Comment: А когда выяснять надо? В процессе установки/обновления?

Answer (score 1):

При запуске получать `[UIDevice identifierForVendor]`, и отправлять себе на сервер. Соответственно, сервер скажет, есть ли у него такой id в базе или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще использовать аналитические сервисы; Flurry и т.д